# How do I query a nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to log (just for now) a particular part of this chain of schemas:

```
const memListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [memSchema]
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  memLists: [memListSchema]
})
```

Here's an example of the data within the user schema:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61a6ac0597698205f546634b"),
"username" : "testing",
"email" : "test@test.test",
"password" : "pass",
"memLists" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "test list 1",
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "question" : "Question 1",
                "answer" : "Answer 1",
                "freq" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("61a6ac0597698205f546634d")
            }, 
            {
                "question" : "Question 2",
                "answer" : "Answer 2",
                "freq" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("61a6ac0597698205f546634e")
            },
        "name" : "test list 2" 
        -- and so on
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("61a6ac0597698205f546634c")
    }
]
```

}

Expected output would be "Test List 1", though I'd also ultimately need access to eg "Question 1" for other parts of the project.

I'm trying to search for a user (no problems here) and log a memList of a given name. Ultimately, I want to be able to push to this array, but just logging it would be amazing for now. I've been trying to do this for weeks now, so I won't go over everything I've tried, as they've all obviously not worked. This is currently how I'm trying to log it:

```
console.log(user.memLists.name("name of list"))
```

or

```
console.log(user.memLists.memList.name("name of list"))
```

and a ton of other permutations.

It works up to logging the user and the memLists, but I can't get any further.

Comment: if you can give sample data in text JSON, and expected output, and the query you tried so far.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include example JSON text and expected output. Two example queries I've tried are at the bottom. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this by looping through the array, it just seems a convoluted way considering how handy a lot of the methods are for Mongoose. Here is, for example, how I added a new mem to an existing memList:

```
User.findOne({
    "_id": _id
},  function(err, foundUser) {
    foundUser.memLists.forEach(function(foundMemList){
        if (foundMemList.name == memList.name) {
            foundMemList.items.push(mem);
            console.log(foundMemList);
            foundUser.save();
        }
    })
})
```

I'd still love to know if there's a better way of doing this or if there is a glaring issue in here that's going to cause issues down the line though.